# How run Ant task remotely over VPN host

Tags: ant, ssh, task, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I need run some Ant tasks on remotely host over remotely host with VPN. Can I use sshexec or not.
For example:
On Teamcity server I run sshexec task to gateway host with VPN and I need run tasks on another host in this VPN.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: (On a different topic, did you check jenkins master-slave setup for such remote tasks?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ant  has [sshexec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) tasks.  Note that this needs third party libraries (jsch.jar) as listed [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies)